# Web Service Application raising events on Web Application

Tags: c#, web-services, events, asmx

I have 2 projects, one of them is a WebApplication Project and the other is a simple WebService Application. The main project references the webservice project and the webservice SHOULD raise an event on the main project.

**Main class of the Web Application:**

```
public class Manager
{
    Service service;

    public Manager()
    {
        service = new Service();
        service.Send += Receive;
    }

    public void Receive(object sender, SingleArgumentEventArgs<object> args)
    {
        var aVar = args.Argument;
    }
}
```

**Service of the Web Service Application:**

```
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public event WSEventHandler Send;

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string HelloWorld(string a1, string a2 = null)
    {
        string value = a1 + a2;
        SingleArgumentEventArgs<object> args = new SingleArgumentEventArgs<object>(value);
        Send(this, args);
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Global.asax on the Web Application:**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Manager manager = new Manager();
}
```

When I set the WebService Application as the startup project, the manager doesnt exist because Application_Start was never called, and the the event calls no one.

When I set the Web Application as the startup project, the service is unaveilable.

When I publish both of them on the server, in the same folder, its as if both projects try but cant interact.

Is there a solution to this other then converting the Web Application into a WebService Application and make it work internally?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant do that you want to look at ajax (if by app you mean browser) and duplex wcf services if you mean the client to a back end server.

basically you cant raise an event like that but there is a pattern that exposes a callback method.